# Mac sample code using USB and CFRunLoopSource

Tags: cocoa, macos, usb, macos-carbon

I'm trying to (re-)write a program that uses USB controlled scanners. I've got my `USBIOInterfaceInterface` set up, so I can send and receive messages over the pipes. I am successfully calling `WritePipeTO` and `ReadPipeTO` synchronously but I want to read from the scanner asynchronously.

I've tried using `ReadPipeAsyncTO`, but the callback never gets called until the call timesout. The reason Appears to be that I'm not registering the callback somewhere. If I add a `CFRunLoopRun`  after the async read, then it appears to work, but only by having many nested calls to `CFRunLoopRun`, which can't be a good idea.

I've seen the functions:

```
    err = (*usbInterfaceInterface)->CreateInterfaceAsyncEventSource(usbInterfaceInterface, &cfSource);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), cfSource, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
```

but I haven't figured out how to tell the Source what callback should be called when something happens on that interface. When I just create the source, and call the `ReadPipeAsyncTO`, the callback doesn't get called until timeout.

Is there same sample code somewhere so I can see how these functions are SUPPOSED to work together?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `CFRunLoopRun`, or its NSRunLoop equivalent, is almost always a sign that your program's architecture is wrong.

It sounds like it would be a terrible pain to do, but your app would be much better—and would work, using the `ReadPipeAsyncTO` and `WritePipeAsyncTO` functions—if you rewrote it to use the run loop instead of whatever manual loop you currently have.

Comment: Can you give me a pointer to sample code that does that? I'm certainly open to suggestions. The original code used a 20 year deprecated function (GetNextEvent) so an architecture change is probably in order anyway...

Comment: Does what? Uses the run loop properly? Any Cocoa application that doesn't directly call `CFRunLoopRun` or `-[NSRunLoop run…]` (or, while we're at it, `-[NSApplication nextEvent::::]`) qualifies. The run loop is there anyway, and the application is built on it, so all you need to do is schedule the asynchronous operation on it, then finish up, return, and let it get back to you in its own time.

Comment: Chances are, you're trying to set up the connection before your run loop is running.  You can't do that with a Foundation run loop, though you can sort of get away with it using a Core Foundation run loop, which is why things are halfway working for you.  Instead of initializing your code before your main run loop starts, initialize it as part of a routine that is already running within a run loop.  Then, ReadPipeAsync[TO] should work as expected.  Also, don't use a timeout if you can help it.